# How do I align an <article> to the right, so that the <article> below stays below is, and I can put an image on the left of this <article>?

Tags: html, css

Sorry if this is a bit lackluster, it's the first time I'm on stack overflow.
I'm doing an HTML assignment for school, where we need to build our own website. How do I put an article on the right of my page, so that no article goes next to it? Thanks in advance!

This is for HTML5 and CSS3, building the site in VS Code. I've tried to make it `float: right;`, but it makes the article below pop up next to it.

Things that I have:

```
<article>Some text Some text some text</article>
<article>More text More text More text</article>
```

Like stated above, I've tried to make it float, but that didn't work as I'd hoped. The only thing that has produced something a bit like what I want, is just a tonne of `padding-left` on the article.

What I'm basically trying, is to make it look like this:

```
                                    Some text Some text some text along with some text

More text More text More text along with more text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example!!!

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
}

.left, .right {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.right {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <article class="right">Some text Some text some text</article>
    <article class="left">More text More text More text</article>
  </div>
</body>
```